# Instantiate new array for each TableViewCell

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary

**The objective**

- Create a new array of strings for each individual table view cell.

**The Problem**

- Every time I append to the array of Strings for each individual JSON Object, the appending doesn't append to the array for each individual cell; the appending is for the whole entire feed of JSON objects, thus, ending up with an array of every JSON object that is being fetched.. (I need a separate array for each separate cell)

  for example =
- cell 1 = ["hello", "thank you", "welcome"]
- cell 2 = ["America", "China", "Russia"]
- cell 3 = ["Patatoe", "Orange", "Apple"]
- Ect...

**What I'm Doing?**

- I'm pulling an array of strings from firebase and appending the values to an empty array instantiated inside the cellForRowAtIndexPath method.

CODE

```
 var peopleWhomAreInvited = [String]()
        
    Database.database().reference().child("following").child((currentUser?.uid)!).observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in
        Database.fetchUserWithUID(uid: snapshot.key) { (user) in
            let allUserRef =  Database.database().reference().child("plans").child((user.uid))
            
            allUserRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                guard let dictionaries = snapshot.value as? [String: Any] else { return }
                dictionaries.forEach({ (key, value) in
                    
                    let peopleAttendingRef = allUserRef.child(key).child("invited").observe(.childAdded, with: { (peopleSnapshot) in
                        let personsRef = allUserRef.child(key).child("invited").child(peopleSnapshot.key)
                        personsRef.observe(.childAdded, with: { (personSnapshot) in
                            guard let peopleAttendingDictionary = personSnapshot.value as? String else { return }
                            peopleWhomAreInvited.append(peopleAttendingDictionary)
                            print("THIS IS WHO I INVITED", peopleWhomAreInvited)
                        })
                    })
                })
                
            })
        }
    })
```

**What Have I Tried?**

I've tried:

- to declare the array outside of the cellForRowAtIndexPath method and in the cell
- create a dictionary with a value of arrays and (unsuccessfully) append the array to each key (which is the indexPath.row).
- declare the fetch method inside the cell and not in the cellForRowAtIndexPath

I'm not sure what to do ... If you have any ideas please let me know.

Comment: 2D Arrays might help you .

Comment: Where are you using the array? The explanation is a bit confusing. Also, peopleWhomAreInvited should be who not whom. The verb 'to be' takes the nominative case.

Comment: make your question little bit clear to understand

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs for clarification, but reading this twice it appeared to me that you want to maintain Array of Arrays and this can be done in following way.

```
var arrayForAppending = [[String]]()

let cellOneArray = ["hello", "thank you", "welcome"]
let cellTwoArray = ["America", "China", "Russia"]
let cellThreeArray = ["Patatoe", "Orange", "Apple"]

arrayForAppending.append(cellOneArray)
arrayForAppending.append(cellTwoArray)
arrayForAppending.append(cellThreeArray)
print(arrayForAppending)

// Print Output
// [["hello", "thank you", "welcome"], ["America", "China", "Russia"], ["Patatoe", "Orange", "Apple"]]
```

Comment: I tried to make it ask clear as possible. This still doesn't answer what i need. For each individual cell (in a table view) it doesn't return a new array.

Answer (score 0):

The fix to this problem is to add the Array to the struct that holds the values for each post. You create a new post object on each cell when instantiating the struct, such as **var post = Post(dictionary: dictionary)**

This post was overcomplicated.